# Java ByteBuffers: Trying to insert two bytes for decimal value 256 in a ByteBuffer Array

Tags: java, byte, buffer

I have this ByteBuffer in Java that I'm filling with data. Before filling the buffer with data, I save the first two bytes to fill later:

```
buffer.put((byte)0); //position 0
buffer.put((byte)0); //position 1
```

Then I fill the buffer with data and calculate the total size of the data I inserted, which can go up to 256 max. So, I need to put the total size of the data I inserted in the first two positions of the BufferArray, that's why I saved them before.

So if I do this:

```
buffer.put(1,(byte)x); // x between 0 and 255
```

When x is between 0 and 255, I only need 1 byte (position 1). After I run the code, I can the hexadecimal result, and see for example 00 FF (x=255. 255 is FF in hexadecimal)

Now if X = 256, I get 00 00, and I need to get 01 00 (256 in Hexadecimal is 100). I need 2 bytes when x = 256. Now, how can I solve this? I can give additional information if I was not clear enough. Thanks.

Comment: Your problem is unclear. What do you get and what do you expect to get instead? Note that a byte in Java is not 0..255 but -128..127.

Comment: Yeah, I suspected that my explanation was not very good but I think they already answered me. Thx anyway

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be using big endian, so you need this:

```
buffer.put( 1, (byte)x );
buffer.put( 0, (byte)(x >> 8) );
```

If you later discover that you needed little endian instead, then you will need to swap the 0 and the 1.

Comment: Yes, I suspected that it might involve binary right shifts! I think your answer is correct, but I can only test tomorrow. Thanks, tomorrow ill confirm

Comment: And it is big endian I think

Comment: Sure.  But I'd suggest that you check EJP's answer.  I looked up `ByteBuffer`, (never used it before,) and it seems to offer the ability to specify the endianness, so `putShort()` is most probably a better choice than my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `ByteBuffer.putShort()` for this task.